# Reject a row based on 2 column values

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the output of a simple join query. All the 3 columns are from different tables.

```
 Col1     Col2        Col3  
Manual   Y-Yes      Include  
MC       Y-Yes      Include  
Manual   Y-Yes      Exclude  
Manual   Y-Yes      Exclude
```

I need to get the rows with 'Include' only if there is no 'Exclude' for the same Col1 value.

If there is no 'Exclude' for the Col1 value, then its fine to display 'Include'.

So the query should not display the first row according to the requirement since the Col1 value 'Manual' has 'Exclude'.

Comment: please edit your question and format so it is readable.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles Bretana for formatting

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query should look a lot like what your question would be in English:
You want all the rows where there is no row for the same `col1` value that has 'Exclude' in the `col3` value, right?
I cannot give exact sql since you do not provide table or column names, but if all three columns were in the same table, it would look like this:

```
Select *  from mytable
where not exists
    (select * from mytable
     where col1 = t.col1
       and col3 = 'Exclude')
```

Comment: All the three columns are from different tables. And this query rejects all columns with 'Exclude'

Comment: The query should only reject the rows having 'Include' if the same Col1 has an 'Exclude' as well.

Comment: Please provide the schema of all three tables, otherwise, how is anyone going to guess at the right SQL syntax? and this query, (if modified to access the correct tables) would exclude the rows as you requested.